# Use batch or Javascript to check if a file is open

Tags: javascript, batch-file

Helle script programmers :)

I need some help making a batch script or Javascript that can check if a pdf file is open by another user on the same network..

The best way I have found is to check if the file can be renamed, but I'm a noob at best, at programming batch script and don't know any thing about Javascript, so I'm putting this task out in the open :)

**The thing I want the script to do:**

- Check if the file can be renamed but don't rename it
- If the file can be renamed, I wan't a msg box to apear with the text saying "The file is free"
- If the file can't be renamed I need a msg box to apear with the text saying "The file is in use. Please try again later"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript can not access the file system of the User's computer. It can only be done on server side. This is done to protect users data from being accessed by unauthorized websites.
if you want such features on the server side then I 'll suggest you go ahead with NodeJS